# Разный id в компоненте b-form-checkbox (Nuxt js + Bootstrap Vue)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть главная страница, в ней лежит компонент формы с **id="123"**:

> *index.vue*

```
<template>
    <b-container class="bg-white" fluid>
        <common-data
                @reset="commonDataResetHandler"
                @submit="commonDataSubmitHandler"
                id="123" 
                :model.sync="forms.commonData.model"
        />
    </b-container>
</template>
```

В самом компоненте формы есть вот такой чекбокс, у которого генерируется **id**:

> *commonData.vue*

```
<b-form-checkbox
        :id="`${generateId}__host-is-participant`"
        v-model="commonData.model.host.value.isParticipant"
>
        {{commonData.model.host.label.isParticipant}}
</b-form-checkbox>
```

**generateId** это не что иное, как геттер:

```
private get generateId(): string {
        //Если свойство id не было задано, то idCast генерируется с помощью uuidv4()
        this.idCast = (this.idCast) ? this.idCast : uuidv4();
        return `common-data-${this.idCast}`;
}
```

**idCast** это переменная, которая принимает значение свойства **id**:

```
@Prop() private id: string;
private idCast: string = this.id;
```

Запускаем... И вот что видим:

[image: Одинаковый id и for]

Ура! Одинаковый **id** и **for** (*как и ожидалось*). Но стоит мне убрать "захардкоженый" **id="123"** (*дав переменной **idCast** сгенерироваться*), то вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Везде **id** как **id**, а в чекбоксе (в **for**) - другой... В чём может быть причина?

P.S. Я пробовал выводить в консоль **generateId** - результат везде одинаковый. Также в ***computed*** видно, что он такой, как во всех остальных элементах формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я даже сделал песочницу, по аналогии с моим кодом (только без nuxt js и без ts):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebRQNy

Но там id не изменяется! Всё работает корректно... Очень странно.

Comment: действительно все работает. А вы не рассматриваете генерацию id `generateId()` на момент создания родительского компонента в хуке, а потом просто пробрасывать props `idCast` дочерним компонентам? Тогда будете уверены, что id один для всех дочерних.

Comment: Попробуйте такой способ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMzJWP

Comment: С "created" та же ситуация, но вот с "mounted" - всё ок. Видимо компонент чекбокс как-то рендерится по особому и генерирует свой label только на конечном хуке до destroy... (?).